# draw image with variable name

Tags: javascript, variables, drawimage

I'm a very beginner with JS, I have a question about using variable names when drawing images, and I didn't find an exact answer for this from earlier posts. I'm sorry if I missed one.

I want to draw a tilemap on canvas, and I have tile images set up like this:

```
var tile00 = new Image();
tile00.src = "SeaTile00.jpg";

var tile01 = new Image();
tile01.src = "SeaTile01.jpg";           

var tile02 = new Image();
tile02.src = "SeaTile02.jpg";
```

etc ...

```
var tile025 = new Image();
tile025.src = "LandTile08.jpg";
```

I would then want to call these later for drawing, with a variable value from a two dimensional 100x100 MapArray, which holds a value (0 to 25) for each map square, like this:

```
 for (i=0;i<100;i++){

     for (j=0;j<100;j++) {

         X = 10*j;
         Y = 10*i;

         ImageName = "tile0" + MapArray[i][j].toString();

         ctx.drawImage(ImageName, X,Y);

     }
 }
```

...

This gives me a type error. But writing for example

```
ctx.drawImage(tile00, X,Y);
```

works fine, so I think I have created the images ok.

Can anyone please help, is there a way to create a img variable to use with `drawImage(img, x,y)` ?

Comment: You need to put your tiles in an array too.

Comment: What is MapArray here. It will be good if you can create a jsFiddle for you code. It would be easy to understand the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create a fiddle, in special with attaching those tile images. I could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageName` is just a string, so trying to draw that as an image will raise an error. If you store each image in an object, you can access them later. I also added a small utility function to set the `src` on an Image object.

```
var createImage = function (src) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    return img;
};

var images = {
    tile00: createImage("SeaTile00.jpg"),
    tile01: createImage("SeaTile01.jpg"),
    tile02: createImage("SeaTile02.jpg"),
    // etc...
};
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
         X = 10 * j;
         Y = 10 * i;
         ctx.drawImage(images["tile0" + MapArray[i][j].toString()], X, Y);
     }
}
```

While this will work, you can ask yourself why not just create the images in the inner loop?

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!